# Which known Targaryens had personal coat of arms in addition to the three headed dragon of House Targaryen?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, object-identification

As the title says, which known Targaryens had personal coat of arms in addition to the three headed dragon of House Targaryen (a red three-headed dragon, breathing flame on black) and what were those customized arms?

The character must have a Targaryen father and legitimacy doesn't count.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*I'm focusing my answer on bastard sons; Aegon's answer has covered pretty much all the legitimate Targaryens, there is no point to duplicate information*

---

## The Great Bastards of Aegon IV

The most famous bastard sons of House Targaryen were the Great Bastards of [Aegon IV](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?title=Aegon_IV_Targaryen); in his deathbed, the King legitimized them all, causing five major rebellions and more than sixty years of troubles; all the males had a personal Coat of Arms derived in part of the standard Targaryen three-headed dragon.

- **[Daemon I Blackfyre](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_I_Blackfyre)**

  He was the most important of the bastard sons of Aegon IV; his father also gave him [Blackfyre](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Blackfyre), the sword of Aegon I, that was considered the real royal heirloom, a symbol of the royalty itself more than a crown.
  Because of this, [he was a pretender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyM8NVl4yBY) to the throne, contesting the succession and legitimacy to rule of [Daeron II](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daeron_II_Targaryen).
  He founded House Blackfyre (named after the sword), and all of his successors bore his arms.
  In his personal arms, he reversed the colors of the Targaryen Coat of Arms: they depicted a black three-headed dragon on a red field.

  [image]
- **[Aegor "Bittersteel" Rivers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegor_Rivers)**

  He was the son of Aegon IV and his fifth mistress [Barba Bracken](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegor_Rivers).
  He was famous fer being the founder and first commander of the [Golden Company](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Golden_Company), the mercenary company that supported many of the Blackfyre Rebellions. One of the mottos of the company was "Beneath the Gold, the Bitter Steel", referencing both the Nickname of Aegor Rivers and the fact that their emblem is a pike supporting the gilded skulls of the previous commanders.
  In his personal arms he combined the Coat of Arms of his parents' Houses; they depicted a fire-breathing red stallion with black wings on a golden field.

  [image]
- **[Brynden "Bloodraven" Rivers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers)**

  He was the son of Aegon IV and his sixth mistress [Melissa Blackwood](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Melissa_Blackwood).
  Being a loyalist during the Blackfyre Rebellions, he served as the Hand for various Targaryen Kings; he was feared by both friends and enemies, he was the head of a vast network of spies and was even reputed a sorceror.
  He adopted a Coat of Arms inspired by his own appearance; he was an albino, and his arms depicted a red eyed White Dragon on a black field.

  [image]

---

## Other bastards

- **[Orys Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Orys_Baratheon)**

  Orys Baratheon was a friend, companion and supposed half-brother of [Aegon the Conqueror](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen), being rumored to be a bastard son of his father Aerion.
  He was a commander during the [Wars of Conquest](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon%27s_Conquest), and had a pivotal role in the conquest of the Stormlands; after the defeat of the last Storm King, [Argilac Durrandon "the Arrogant"](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Argilac_Durrandon), he married his daughter Argella and took the crowned stag of House Durrandon as his own arms.

  [image]

---

## House Blackfyre

[House Blackfyre](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Blackfyre) was born when Daemon I rebelled against the rule of Daeron II (see above). It can be considered an illegitimate cadet branch of the Targaryens by all means.
Their members bore the reversed arms of Daemon I as their House arms.

- **[Daemon II Blackfyre](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_II_Blackfyre)**

  He was the son of Daemon I, and became the head of his House when his father and his senior twin sons, [Aegon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Blackfyre) and [Aemon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aemon_Blackfyre), died on the battle known as the [Redgrass Field](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Redgrass_Field).
  He was the pretender during the Second Blackfyre Rebellion. He usually bore the standard Blacfyre arms; during the  preparation of the rebellion, he hid his real identity and disguised himself as a hedge knight named **John the Fiddler**.
  Likewise, he took different arms while under cover: they depicted an engrailed golden cross on a blue field, charged with a golden fiddle on the first and third quarters, and a golden sword on the second and fourth ones.
  It is not known why he chose these arms, but probably they were taken just because they were something completely unrelated to his House's.

  [image]

Comment: Good catch on John the Fiddler.

Comment: Hah [We were discussing adding Fiddler](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40097155#40097155) to the list yesterday but then dropped the idea because he doesn't meet the Criteria of having a Targ father (Since his father is a Blackfyre)

Comment: @Aegon Yes, I was considering this too, but I have added it nonetheless at least to provide something different; one could argue that the Blackfyres are not Targaryens merely by the twists of history, that made them the losing party of the civil wars. Daemon I was a son of two Targs, he was legitimized and was considering himself the true heir of Aegon IV; if he won the war, I suppose that he would have been recognized as pertaining to the main lineage, and Daeron II and his successors as a mere cadet branch.

Answer (score 18):

The following Targaryens had customized Coats of Arms:

#### 1. [Rhaenyra Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenyra_Targaryen)

Her coat of arms is described as "*The Targaryen three-headed red dragon on black, quartered with the moon-and-falcon sigil of House Arryn and the silver seahorse on sea green of House Velaryon*".

She has Falcon of Arryn for her mother, Queen Aemma Arryn and Velaryon Seahorse for her late husband, Ser Laenor Velaryon.

> their neighbor had taken up Rhaenyra's red dragon quartered with the
> moon-and-falcon of her Arryn mother and the seahorse of her late
> husband.
> <sub>***TWOIAF: Targaryen Kings - Aegon II***</sub>

[image]

#### 2. [Aegon II](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_II_Targaryen)

His coat of arms is described as *"A golden three-headed dragon on black"*. Reasoning unknown but probably for the King's Dragon, Sunfyre the Golden, the most beautiful dragon to ever take wing in Westeros and as Golden as the Sun.

> Men raised the banner of the king, bearing the golden three-headed
> dragon that Aegon had taken for his sigil
> <sub>***TWOIAF: Targaryen Kings - Aegon II***</sub>

[image]

#### 3. [Daemon Blackfyre](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_I_Blackfyre)

Born Daemon Waters, bastard of Aegon IV. Legitimized by his father and founded his own dynasty, House Blackfyre. His coat of arms is described as *"a black three headed-dragon on red"*. He just inverted the colors of House Targaryen like many bastards did.

> Red or black? was a dangerous question, even now. Since the days of
> Aegon the Conquerer, the arms of House Targaryen had borne a
> three-headed dragon, red on black. Daemon the Pretender had reversed
> those colors on his own banners, as many bastards did.
> <sub>***The Sworn Sword***</sub>

[image]

#### 4. [Brynden "Bloodraven"](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers)

Born Brynden Rivers, a bastard of Aegon IV. Later legitimized by his father. His arms is described as *"Singled headed Dragon white on black, breathing red flames"*. The White Dragon depicts him, an albino.

> And above them all flew two regal dragons on night-black fields: the
> great three-headed beast of King Aerys I Targaryen, red as fire, and a
> white winged fury breathing scarlet flame. Not Maekar after all, Dunk
> knew, when he saw those banners. The banners of the Prince of
> Summerhall showed four three-headed dragons, two and two, the arms of
> the fourth-born son of the late King Daeron II Targaryen. A single
> white dragon announced the presence of the King's Hand, Lord Brynden
> Rivers.
> <sub>***The Mystery Knight***</sub>

Also [Quoting GRRM](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/The_Great_Bastards/):

> His colors are "scarlet and smoke," smoke being a sort of dark grey
> streaked and mottled with black. Because his skin is very senstive to
> the rays of the sun, he frequently goes about cloaked and hooded.
>
> His sigil is a white dragon (one-headed) with red eyes.

[image]

#### 5. [Aegor "Bittersteel"](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegor_Rivers)

Born Aegor Rivers, a bastard of Aegon IV. Later legitimized by his father. His coat of Arms is described as *"A red stallion with black wings snorting flame on gold"*. He took the Red Stallion of Bracken for his mother and added Dragon wings and flame for his father.

[Quoting GRRM](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/The_Great_Bastards/):

> So here's Bittersteel: a winged red stallion on a golden field. Only
> the horse has big black dragon wings instead of the usual
> Pegasus-style feathered angel wings, and he's snorting fire.

[image]

#### 6. [Maekar Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maekar_I_Targaryen)

His Coat of Arms is described as *"The Targaryen three-headed red dragon on black, quartered"*. The four Three headed Dragons are a reference to him being fourth son of King Daeron II.

> The banners of the Prince of Summerhall showed four three-headed
> dragons, two and two, the arms of the fourth-born son of the late King
> Daeron II Targaryen.
> <sub>***The Mystery Knight***</sub>

[image]

#### 7. [Aerion "Brightflame"](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerion_Targaryen)

His Coat of Arms is described as *"a red three-headed dragon on black; one head orange, one yellow, one red, breathing golden flames"*. Bright Prince liked bright colors.

> Aerion bore a three-headed dragon on his shield, but it was rendered
> in colors much more vivid than Valarr's; one head was orange, one
> yellow, one red, and the flames they breathed had the sheen of gold
> leaf. His surcoat was a swirl of smoke and fire woven together, and
> his blackened helm was surmounted by a crest of red enamel flames.
> <sub>***The Hedge Knight***</sub>

[image]

#### 8. [Valarr Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Valarr_Targaryen)

His Coat of Arms is described as *"Black, the red three-headed dragon of House Targaryen, with a red border"*. Reasoning unknown.

[image]

#### 9. [Daeron "the Drunken"](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daeron_Targaryen_(son_of_Maekar_I))

Semi canon AWOIAF wiki suggests that his personal arms were Red three headed dragon on Black field, contourny. Reasoning unknown.

[image]

Elio and Linda, co-authors of TWOIAF, [have confirmed](https://twitter.com/westerosorg/status/910427838620332032) that the entries in AWOIAF wiki for Valarr and Daeron are accurate and they aren't mentioned in any books.

> The source is the "Roll of Arms" for the tourney that George provided
> to us and Dabel Bros for "The Hedge Knight" graphic novel.

[image]

Comment: I was sure that you already had your answer ready! I will try to improve mine to make it more useful (if I can find how) :)

Comment: @Sekhemty There aren't enough questions on heraldry :(

Comment: There aren't enough authors obsessed with description of heraldry and food ;)

Comment: @Aegon I gave up on mine and started eating lemon cakes.

Comment: @Skooba it is hard to beat Aegon with ASOIAF related answers, even when he was the one asking the question ;)

Comment: You _could_ be a smartass and list [Jon Snow](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/File:House_Stark_(Jon_Snow).svg) in there somewhere :p.

Comment: @Möoz Maybe next book/next season when he realizes his ancestry and decides his arms :D

Comment: @Aegon it seems that you have used the image of [Daeron I](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daeron_I_Targaryen) instead of [Aegon II](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_II_Targaryen)

Comment: @Sekhemty yes intentionally. It's only fair that if I'm showing rhaenyra at her prime, I should show aegon at his prime. Plus golden Dragon on the armor works out nicely. Plus both used same crown and sword.

Comment: @Aegon Sorry but I can't understand... that is not Aegon... isn't it misleading?

Comment: @Sekhemty, not really. It's fan art anyways not canon. The official portraits for Aegon and Daeron both are way different in Twoiaf

Comment: @Aegon I really don't get it. Portraits from Amok are known to be accurate and faithful to Martin's descriptions of Targ kings. Why you consider the real depiction of Aegon not appropriate?

Comment: @Sekhemty I thought we started there and I told you why. Well to repeat it, I'm using rhaenyra's younger and beautiful depiction when she was fit. There is no similar depiction of Aegon except his teenage slim black and white sketch in twoiaf. All depict the man he became, fat and ungainly, not at his prime. That's why I used Daeron cus that balances the two. And daeron is wearing golden dragon on his armor and both aegon and daeron used same crown and same sword. Makes sense? I'm not saying amok is wrong in his portrait, aegon was fat when he became king.

Comment: @Sekhemty the portrait on awoiaf is accurate but accurate at the particular instance of time when Aegon took the throne. It doesn't show Aegon at his peak physical condition. I supported him in the Dance so I can't bear to have him outshone by younger Rhaenyra. Had I used rhaenyra's fat portrait then I'd used the same for Aegon. So tldr, it's a bit emotional for me. I'm sorry if it upsets you (I know the feeling when something is wrong), but use your imagination and think it's Aegon before his marriage alcoholism

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but this just doesn't seems right, it is an inaccuracy, even if intentional and rational. The descriptions that Martin gave to Amok were intended to be a representation of how these kings were remembered and what was considered their most representative likeness; pretty much like Henry VIII of England was a large and imposing man in his later years, while in his youth he was very different (but nobody remember him like that); anyway, this is not so important after all, it isn't worth to start a duel here ;) Your answer, your preferences :)

Comment: @Aegon It is worth noting that [Aemon the Dragonknight](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aemon_Targaryen_(son_of_Viserys_II)) was known for a crest resembling the three-headed dragon made of *white gold*; while probably this was because he wore the white garments of the Kingsuard, he was the only one known to carry this emblem; not a real Coat of Arms, but probably on could infer that this could be considered his personal [heraldic badge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraldic_badge)

Answer (score 6):

There were many Targaryen's who took personal sigils and of course one whole house, that of the Blackfyres.

- **[House Blackfyre](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/Heraldry/Entry/House_Blackfyre/)** - A black three-headed dragon, breathing black fire on red

  [image]
- **[Prince Aerion Targaryen](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/Heraldry/Entry/Prince_Aerion_Targaryen/)** - A dragon of three heads, orange, yellow and red, breathing golden flames on black

  [image]
- **[Ser Aegor "Bittersteel" Rivers](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/Heraldry/Entry/Ser_Aegor_Rivers/)** - A red stallion with black wings snorting flame on gold

  [image]
- [**Ser Brynden "Bloodraven" Rivers**](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/Heraldry/Entry/Ser_Brynden_Rivers/) - A white dragon on black, breathing red fire

  [image]

Comment: Ah the infamous "list item" a great coat of arms

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of any others but the obvious answer is [House Blackfyre](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Blackfyre):

[image: House Blackfyre coat of arms]

This house was formed by Daemon Blackfyre a legitimised bastard Aegon IV Targaryen.

Note even though the coat of arms is a three headed dragon the colours are inverted.